# MAUI going back to a specific page is not smooth

Tags: c#, maui

Going back to specific page causes the transition to be choppy and shows pages that were open between those pages for 0.5 seconds. How to avoid it?

It's ok when I do it:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"..");
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"../../");
```

and I have this problems if trying to undo like this:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"../{nameof(MainPage)}");
```

Comment: Which platform?  Which OS level?

Comment: If you add to shell a new blank page `MyBlankPage`, then do `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"../{nameof(MyBlankPage)}");`, do you still see inbetween pages? I'm wondering if this bug only happens when a page takes a while to load. If blank page works, then need more details about what happens when MainPage loads. Is it loading data or images that might take awhile? If blank page works, then a work-around could be to DEFER much of the work. Details TBD, after you do this test.

Comment: @Jason I tested only Android

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I was going to the page which has 1/3 controls. I can test it later on a blank page

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve don't see any differences

Comment: I can't think of anything else to try differently. Might be a bug in Maui. You can make a new issue at `github maui issues`, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the form "GoToAsync(ShellNavigationState state, Boolean animate)" of the method, with "animate = false" to avoid animations. See: [MAUI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shell.gotoasync?view=net-maui-6.0#microsoft-maui-controls-shell-gotoasync(microsoft-maui-controls-shellnavigationstate-system-boolean)) for details. I hope this helps.